# access navigationController from a viewController that i opened using modal in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

i am using navigationController (push and pop) but in a special case i have to show the next viewcontroller using modal segue , and when i dismiss that modal i want to pop the last viewController in the navigationController and then push a new one to appear after dismissing the modal one , how can i access the navigationController that is full of viewControllers from a modal viewController 
i can send in the last element in navigationController as self in prepareForSegue for the modal but i am asking if there is another way , sorry my questions are always complicated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [delegation](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/04/08/how-delegation-works-a-swift-developer-guide/) or [notifications](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/10/08/fundamentals-of-nsnotificationcenter-in-swift/), depending on how you want to go about it. In either case—your `navigationController` can either be notified to perform the segue at the right time, or accessed and instructed to do so as a delegate.

Answer (score 12):

This will work if  your navigationController is the rootViewController

```
if let navigationController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {

        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4 answer:

```
if let navigationController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
//Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`UIApplication.shared.keyWindow` is deprecated on iOS13.0.

For iOS 13.0 or later.

```
if let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow }), let navigationController = keyWindow.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
    // do something
}
```